# Android studio will not start for lack of Java

Tags: android-studio

Android studio used to work fine on my machine, ubuntu 22.04 64bit. Then I deleted everything connected with it in ./config, ./local, ./cache and now the latest Android Iguana (and friends) will not start. `./studio.sh` says `No JRE found. Please make sure $STUDIO_JDK, $JDK_HOME, or $JAVA_HOME point to valid JRE installation.`
I know my Java installation is good because Jetbrains IDE is running fine.

I run `echo $JAVA_HOME` and the result: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-18-openjdk-amd64`

What could be the issue?

Comment: What about `$JDK_HOME` and `$STUDIO_JDK`? And have you done a clean re-install?

Comment: I have never installed android studio. All I do is download the tar ball, extract it and run the file `studio.sh`

Comment: Never mind. All of a sudden, it starts to run now. Do not know why.